# How can I capture the error returned from mysqldump and use it to take another action in a shell script?

Tags: shell, mysql

I'm using mysqldump in a shell script to dump several schemas from a production environment to a local one.

```
schemas = (one two three)
read -p "Enter Username: " un   
read -s -p "Enter Password: " pw
for schema in "${schemas[@]}"
do
  :
  mysqldump -h SERV -u $un --password=$p > /dev/null 2>&1 | mysql -uroot LOCAL
done
```

I'm redirecting out and error to /dev/null to prevent warnings and error messages, but I want to be able to catch the error and do something else based on the output (e.g. Access Denied, Not Found).

How can I capture the error returned from mysqldump and use it to take another action in a shell script?

For what it's worth, the `$?` variable always seems to be `0` after mysqldump completes, even if the STDERR is access denied.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little more research and found the answer here:

http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2011/01/bash-how-to-check-exit-status-of-pipe.html